# How can I make an \if conditional reusable?

Tags: listings, conditionals

This is related to a previous question of mine, [how to use listings in conditionals](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/689890/how-can-i-use-listings-in-conditionals).

I'm using the answer kindly provided there to include different code snippets when their library of origin is included in different documents. Now I would like to do the same for other libraries/documents without writing a new \if every time. In other words, I would like to make the conditional itself reusable.

Up until now, I've worked with \IfSubStr, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to pack the new \if into a reusable macro.

To illustrate what I'm talking about, this has been my way of using conditionals for regular text (which works fine):

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\ifjobnamecontains}{ m +m +m }{%     
   \IfSubStr{\jobname}{\detokenize{#1}}%       
    {#2}%  
    {#3}%
    }

>>>>

\ifjobnamecontains{<DOCUMENTA>}{Here is text that goes in Document A.}
  {Here is text that goes in all documents that are not Document A.}
```

However, I can't use this type of conditional for code snippets. Is there any way to make the \if conditional from the following MWE similarly reusable? (Note: The document name in this MWE is MWE.tex).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\newif\ifmwe
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xstring}

\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,breaklines=true}

\begin{document}

Here is lstlisting within a conditional:

\IfSubStr{\jobname}{\detokenize{MWE}}%
  {\mwetrue}%true
  {\mwefalse}%false
  
\ifmwe
  \begin{lstlisting}
      This is sample code. 
     \end{lstlisting}  
\else
 fasle
\fi
```

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/355085/233251 (the answer explaining that "You can't easily pass verbatim content as part of macro arguments" and suggests an alternative option)

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll look into it. :-)